# Angular 4 issue with DOM duplicate IDs on dynamic form

Tags: angular

I'm having an issue with the DOM complaining (non-fatally) about duplicate IDs when I'm adding 1-n dynamic contacts to a form.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Error: [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #contactFirstName:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contactsSection">
 <div formArrayName="contacts">
   <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let contact of 
       this.editForm.controls.contacts.controls; let i = index" 
         [formGroupName]="i">
       <div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
             <label for="contactFirstName">First Name:<sup>*</sup></label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactFirstName" 
                    name="contactFirstName" 
                       formControlName="contactFirstName" 
                       required placeholder="First Name">

**Typescript Code:** 
To initialize the form:

    this.editProducerForm = this.fb.group({
      ...
      contacts: this.fb.array([])
    });

To add a contact dynamically to the form I call:

    let control = this.editProducerForm.get('contacts') as FormArray;
    control.push(this.createContact(firstName,...));

which uses this method:

    createContact(firstName: string = '',...): FormGroup {
        let ctc = this.fb.group({
          contactId: id,
          contactFirstName: [firstName, Validators.required ],
          contactMobilePhone: [mobilePhone, CustomValidators.phone ],
          contactAgentLicense: agentlicense,
          contactLastName: [lastName, Validators.required ],
          contactEmail: [email, CustomValidators.email ],
          contactAgentLicenseExpirationDate: licenseExpirationDate,
          contactTitle: [titleUid, Validators.required ],
          ssn: ss
        });
        ctc.markAsUntouched();
        return ctc;
      }
```

EDIT:
I tried the solution of adding the index to each control id.  I don't believe this is a viable solution because I have to coordinate the code to access each control and mostly because if breaks the formbuilder code that is used to dynamically add each group of controls:
   let ctc = this.fb.group({
      contactId: id,
      contactFirstName: [firstName, Validators.required ],
      contactMobilePhone: [mobilePhone, CustomValidators.pattern ],
      contactAgentLicense: agentlicense,
      contactLastName: [lastName, Validators.required ],...

Interestingly, when I run this code via an event (button push), the DOM doesn't complain.  When I run the same code as part of initialize, it does complain.

Since each FormGroup has a unique name, is the DOM not smart enough to realize a unique FormGroup/Control Id is unique as opposed to looking at each Control Id indepent of FormGroup name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index` to generate unique id's:

```
<label [for]="'contactFirstName' + i">First Name:<sup>*</sup></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [id]="'contactFirstName' + i"  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought of that and was keeping it in my back pocket as a last resort, but it would complicate all of my code in which I iterate over the 1-n groups of controls to get the values of the various fields.